# Bazel genrule Check if location expression expands to no files

Tags: cmd, bazel, bazel-aspect, bazel-extra-action

I am writing a `genrule` in Bazel. I have a file withing a folder that may or may not exist. I want to reference it if it does but ignore it if it does not. How do i do an conditional check in the cmd part of the `genrule` before doing `$(location my_file_that_may_or_may_not_exist)`?

When the file does not exist I get 
`$(location)` expression expands to no files error. This is expected so I want to avoid it